# Android Xamarin - net call with ip adress failing for mobile data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webclient, mobile-application

I'm caught up in weird issue. I'm making web call using below simple code in my .Net Native Android App

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var data = client.DownloadString("http://172.217.12.174");
```

It was all working fine on API 25 until I recently upgraded it to 29.

Issue is it works fine on wifi connection but fails when switched to mobile data. I only see Timeout exception in debug though. 
However it works if I put same url in chrome browser on mobile data.

My initial investigation found this is happening for any ip address based url (I have tried with Google.com IP address above and has same issue). So I think its some issue with Webclient. I have Samsung 10+ only to test with mobile connection so not sure if its problem with my device.

Comment: Have you tried using HttpClient instead of WebClient? If you have bumped your API to target 29, you may be running into SSL issues, where plaintext web-pages fail to load. See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html for more information on how to allow that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to some good resource on breaking changes with API 29. I tried setting android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest. Also tried network config file with <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"></base-config>. But nothing works. Even if it was this issue it doesn't explain why it works on wifi connection but fails in mobile data. Also my other calls with WebClient or HttpWebRequest works fine for url with domain over http.

Comment: How do you switch to mobile data? Does the network works well after switch?

Comment: I'm switching it from quick action panel. Everything else works fine except url with IP address using WebClient /HttpWebRequest calls. Same code works fine for url with domain name.

Comment: You could check the NetworkReachability before you use the WebClient /HttpWebRequest calls. i guess when you chenge the wife to mobile data, the connection is technically no longer usable.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-device-using-dependency-service-xamarin-form/

Comment: Thanks, I tried creating new client every time and its new http request every time it makes call. Also I have other requests going on same time that had domain name in url which works perfectly fine. So I dont think its network switching issue. Must be some security feature or internal name resolution issue causing it.